# Secondary graphic card not work after install NVIDIA driver -- login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have NVIDIA graphic card along with another card from ASPEED. I would like to use NVIDIA card for scientific computing and ASPEED card for displaying. 
The ASPEED card works OK initially, but after the NVIDIA driver is installed, it stuck in a login loop.

Below are more information.

```
pixels@pixels-SYS-7048GR:~$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)
82:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)
83:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)

pixels@pixels-SYS-7048GR:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Nov 10 10:38:33 2016
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   42C    P0    68W / 250W |      0MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   47C    P0    75W / 250W |      0MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:82:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   46C    P0    72W / 250W |      0MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P0    55W / 250W |      0MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file, it shows error message. I googled the error message, but no efficient solution found.

(EE) ast: The PCI device 0x2000 at 06@00:00:0 has a kernel module claiming it.

(EE) ast: This driver cannot operate until it has been unloaded.

I think the following is the most relevant one:
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
    pixels@pixels-SYS-7048GR:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[    51.002] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    51.002] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    51.002] Current Operating System: Linux pixels-SYS-7048GR 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    51.002] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-45-generic root=UUID=2fba102f-2fa2-4dfa-bd89-2ff9da50e97a ro quiet splash
[    51.002] Build Date: 18 May 2016  01:07:07AM
[    51.002] xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    51.002] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    51.002]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    51.002] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    51.002] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Nov 10 09:40:16 2016
[    51.002] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    51.003] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    51.003] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    51.003] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    51.003] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    51.003] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    51.003] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    51.003] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    51.003] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    51.003] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    51.003] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    51.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    51.003] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    51.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    51.003] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    51.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    51.003] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    51.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    51.003] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    51.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    51.003] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[    51.003] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    51.003] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    51.003] (II) Loader magic: 0x56045b3d2da0
[    51.003] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    51.003]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    51.003]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    51.003]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    51.003]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    51.003] (++) using VT number 7

[    51.003] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    51.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    51.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card2)
[    51.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    51.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card3)
[    51.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card4)
[    51.010] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 10de:17c2:10de:1132 rev 161, Mem @ 0xcf000000/16777216, 0x383fe0000000/268435456, 0x383ff0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00006000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    51.010] (--) PCI: (0:3:0:0) 10de:17c2:10de:1132 rev 161, Mem @ 0xcd000000/16777216, 0x383fc0000000/268435456, 0x383fd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00005000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    51.010] (--) PCI:*(0:6:0:0) 1a03:2000:15d9:0852 rev 48, Mem @ 0xcb000000/16777216, 0xcc000000/131072, I/O @ 0x00004000/128
[    51.010] (--) PCI: (0:130:0:0) 10de:17c2:10de:1132 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0x387fe0000000/268435456, 0x387ff0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    51.010] (--) PCI: (0:131:0:0) 10de:17c2:10de:1132 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf8000000/16777216, 0x387fc0000000/268435456, 0x387fd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    51.010] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    51.010] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    51.010] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    51.010] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    51.014] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    51.014]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.014]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    51.014] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:28:17 PDT 2016
[    51.014] (==) Matched ast as autoconfigured driver 0
[    51.014] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[    51.014] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[    51.014] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 3
[    51.014] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 4
[    51.014] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 5
[    51.014] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 6
[    51.014] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 7
[    51.014] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 8
[    51.014] (==) Matched ast as autoconfigured driver 9
[    51.014] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 10
[    51.014] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 11
[    51.014] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 12
[    51.014] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    51.014] (II) LoadModule: "ast"
[    51.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ast_drv.so
[    51.014] (II) Module ast: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.014]    compiled for 1.18.0, module version = 1.2.6
[    51.014]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.014]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.014] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    51.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    51.014] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    51.014]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.014]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.014] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    51.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    51.015] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.015]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 1.0.12
[    51.015]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.015]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.015] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    51.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    51.015] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.015]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.18.3
[    51.015]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.015]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.015] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    51.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    51.015] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.015]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    51.015]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.015]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.015] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    51.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    51.015] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.015]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    51.015]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.015]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.015] (II) ASPEED: Driver for ASPEED Graphics Chipsets: ASPEED Graphics Family,
        ASPEED Graphics Family, ASPEED AST1180 Graphics, AIP100, AIP200
[    51.015] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:03:48 PDT 2016
[    51.015] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    51.015] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Dec 8 15:52:25 2015 +1000
[    51.015] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    51.015]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    51.015]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    51.015]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    51.015]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    51.015]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    51.015]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    51.015]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    51.015]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    51.015]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    51.015]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    51.015]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    51.015]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    51.015]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    51.015] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    51.015] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    51.015] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    51.015] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for ast
[    51.015] (--) Assigning device section with no busID to primary device
[    51.015] (--) Assigning device section with no busID to primary device
[    51.015] (WW) ASPEED: More than one matching Device section found: Autoconfigured Video Device ast
[    51.015] (--) Chipset ASPEED Graphics Family found
**[    51.015] (EE) ast: The PCI device 0x2000 at 06@00:00:0 has a kernel module claiming it.
[    51.015] (EE) ast: This driver cannot operate until it has been unloaded.
[    51.015] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    51.015] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    51.015] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    51.015] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22**
[    51.015] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    51.015] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    51.015] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    51.015] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    51.015] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    51.015] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.015]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    51.016]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    51.016] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    51.016] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    51.016] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    51.016] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[    51.016] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    51.016] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[    51.016] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    51.016] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    51.019] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.019]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.019]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    51.019] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[    51.034] (EE) modeset(0): eglInitialize() failed
[    51.034] (EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed
[    51.034] (II) modeset(0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[    51.113] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: 4071  Serial#: 876098114
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2014  Week: 10
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.300 V
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Sync:  Separate  Composite  SyncOnGreen
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 51  vert.: 29
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    51.192] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display


...
...
    [    51.768] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: always reports core events
    [    51.768] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Vendor 0x24ae Product 0x2000
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found 9 mouse buttons
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found scroll wheel(s)
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found relative axes
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found x and y relative axes
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found absolute axes
    [    51.768] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
    [    51.768] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found keys
    [    51.768] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Configuring as mouse
    [    51.768] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Configuring as keyboard
    [    51.768] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Adding scrollwheel support
    [    51.768] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
    [    51.768] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
    [    51.768] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:24AE:2000.0002/input/input3/event3"
    [    51.768] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
    [    51.768] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
    [    51.768] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
    [    51.768] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    [    51.768] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: initialized for relative axes.
    [    51.768] (WW) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: ignoring absolute axes.
    [    51.768] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
    [    51.768] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration profile 0
    [    51.768] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
    [    51.768] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
    [    51.768] (II) config/udev: Adding input device RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device (/dev/input/mouse0)
    [    51.768] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.768] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0557:2419 (/dev/input/event4)
    [    51.769] (**) HID 0557:2419: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
    [    51.769] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 0557:2419'
    [    51.769] (**) HID 0557:2419: always reports core events
    [    51.769] (**) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
    [    51.769] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Vendor 0x557 Product 0x2419
    [    51.769] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found keys
    [    51.769] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Configuring as keyboard
    [    51.769] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13.1/3-13.1:1.0/0003:0557:2419.0003/input/input4/event4"
    [    51.769] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 0557:2419" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
    [    51.769] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
    [    51.769] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
    [    51.769] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    [    51.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0557:2419 (/dev/input/event5)
    [    51.769] (**) HID 0557:2419: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
    [    51.769] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 0557:2419'
    [    51.769] (**) HID 0557:2419: always reports core events
    [    51.769] (**) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Vendor 0x557 Product 0x2419
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found 3 mouse buttons
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found scroll wheel(s)
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found relative axes
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found absolute axes
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found x and y absolute axes
    [    51.824] (--) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Found absolute touchscreen
    [    51.824] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Configuring as touchscreen
    [    51.824] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Adding scrollwheel support
    [    51.824] (**) evdev: HID 0557:2419: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
    [    51.824] (**) evdev: HID 0557:2419: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
    [    51.824] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13.1/3-13.1:1.1/0003:0557:2419.0004/input/input5/event5"
    [    51.824] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 0557:2419" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 11)
    [    51.824] (WW) evdev: HID 0557:2419: touchpads, tablets and touchscreens ignore relative axes.
    [    51.824] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: initialized for absolute axes.
    [    51.824] (**) HID 0557:2419: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
    [    51.824] (**) HID 0557:2419: (accel) acceleration profile 0
    [    51.824] (**) HID 0557:2419: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
    [    51.824] (**) HID 0557:2419: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
    [    51.824] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0557:2419 (/dev/input/js0)
    [    51.824] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.824] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.824] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 0557:2419 (/dev/input/mouse1)
    [    51.824] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.824] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event6)
    [    51.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
    [    51.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
    [    51.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event9)
    [    51.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.825] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event10)
    [    51.825] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.825] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.826] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event11)
    [    51.826] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.826] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.826] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event14)
    [    51.826] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.826] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.826] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event15)
    [    51.826] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.826] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.826] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
    [    51.826] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.826] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    51.826] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event13)
    [    51.826] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
    [    51.826] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 16497
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
    [    52.693] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 16497
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
    [    53.543] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
    [  2101.494] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.495] (II) evdev: HID 0557:2419: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.495] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.495] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.495] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.495] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
    [  2101.495] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
    [  2101.497] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

What should I do to make the xserver work, or anything else I can test to get further information?

Many thanks.

Comment: I solved this problem by reinstalling the driver with the following configuration: sudo ./NVIDIAxxxxx.run --no-opengl-files

Comment: Thanks a lot for a wonderful article. It helped me solved my problem too. I am running a deep learning server, which I believe is the same model as you, and then after I installed nvidia driver, ubuntu failed to log in. It took me three days to find your article and now the problem solved. Thank you. But I wonder have you happened to have a problem with your ASPEED video card with X, the message is possible missing firmware?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling the driver with the following Command:

```
sudo ./NVIDIAxxxxx.run --no-opengl-files
```

Reference:
http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/